# Is there a command to stop fire damage in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a little dungeon and I wanted to know if there was a command to stop people from burning. I have buttons to `tp` all players, and some may still be on fire, and I don't want them to be on fire after they're teleported.

Comment: _some_ players or _some_ buttons?

Comment: You could give them some fire resistance with the effect command

Answer (score 2):

Players in creative lose the fire effect immediately after leaving fire. If you toggle the players you teleport into creative immediately, i.e. /gamemode 1 @a, then back to survival (/gamemode 0 @a) then the fire effects will go out.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode <creative|survival> @a`

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific command for it, but there is probably some commandblock contraption that can put the fire out.

Optional: give the player fire resistant (potion effect)

Answer (score 1):

There is a command that you can use or choose this setting when you make your Minecraft world: `/gamerule fireDamage false`. I use this command a lot when I do Survival Mode. It's really useful since fire can be really deadly sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If your players are burning, you can try:

- Whenever you trigger a teleport, send everyone into a room filled with water, before teleporting them to their proper destinations.

Comment: I believe buttons isn't part of the question. **stop people from burning**,*as certain buttons tp all players,* this most likely means he has a button to tp all players and some of those players may be on fire.